# Calling a component in NextJS through a variable

Tags: next.js, components

I am developing a website built with NextJS.
The API loads a variable like the one below:

```
const components = {
    "Welcome": {
      title: "Welcome to Page",
      subtitle: "This is my subtitle",
    },
    "GrayBox": {
      image: "/image.png",
      title: "This is title",
      content: "This is content",
      btnText: "Button Text"
    }
  }
```

The current code works like this:

```
...
return (
 <>  
      {
        Object.keys(components).map((key) => {
          const component = components[key];
          if(key === "Welcome"){
            return <Welcome />;
          } else if(key === "GrayBox"){
            return <GrayBox image={component.image} title={component.title} content={component.content} btnText={component.btnText} />;
          }
          return null;
        })
      }
    </>
)
```

I don't like that all components are loaded in this way. I want the component to be loaded from a variable and the data from an array or object.  I want to use it differently, for example;

```
export default function Home() {

const componentName = "GrayBox";
const datas = [...]

return (
   <${componentName} {...datas} />
);
}
```

I don't know what to try, so I'm waiting for your advice.